# extracting names and numbers using regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I think I might have some issues with understanding the regular expressions in R.

I need to extract phone numbers and names from a sample vector and create a data-frame with corresponding columns for names and numbers using stringr package functionality.

The following is my sample vector.

```
phones <- c("Ann 077-789663", "Johnathan 99656565",
            "Maria2 099-65-6569 office")
```

The code that I came up with to extract those is as follows

```
numbers <- str_remove_all(phones, pattern = "[^0-9]")
numbers <- str_remove_all(numbers, pattern = "[a-zA-Z]")
numbers <- trimws(numbers)

names <- str_remove_all(phones, pattern = "[A-Za-z]+", simplify = T)

phones_data <- data.frame("Name" = names, "Phone" = numbers)
```

It doesn't work, as it takes the digit in the name and joins with the phone number. (not optimal code as well)

I would appreciate some help in explaining the simplest way for accomplishing this task.

Comment: @Onyambu could you explain this a bit more?

Comment: `strcapture("(\\w+)\\s(\\S+)",phones,data.frame(names=character(),phone=character()))`

Comment: `read.table(text=phones,col.names = c("names","phone","office"),fill=T)`

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to have only names without digits in them and numbers without dashes in them, using "stringr" package. Thanks anyways.

Comment: `data.frame(names=str_extract(phones,"^\\w+"),phones=str_extract(phones,"\\b\\d[^ ]*"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a regex expert, however with `stringr` package we can extract a number pattern with optional "-" in it and replace the "-" with empty string to extract numbers without any "-". For names, we extract the first word at the beginning of the string.

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(Name = str_extract(phones, "^[A-Za-z]+"), 
           Number = gsub("-","",str_extract(phones, "[0-9]+[-]?[0-9]+[-]?[0-9]+")))


#       Name    Number
#1       Ann 077789663
#2 Johnathan  99656565
#3     Maria 099656569
```

---

If you want to stick completely with `stringr` we can use `str_replace_all` instead of `gsub`

```
data.frame(Name = str_extract(phones, "[A-Za-z]+"), 
Number=str_replace_all(str_extract(phones, "[0-9]+[-]?[0-9]+[-]?[0-9]+"), "-",""))

#       Name    Number
#1       Ann 077789663
#2 Johnathan  99656565
#3     Maria 099656569
```

Comment: This was very helpful, I'm giving you the best answer. However, one more question? If I were not to use gsub(), would it hold similar result with str_replace() ?

Comment: @MarkHovsepyan actually, we need to use `str_replace_all` instead. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think Ronak's answer is good for the name part, I don't really have a good alternative to offer there.

For numbers, I would go with "numbers and hyphens, with a word boundary at either end", i.e.

```
numbers = str_extract(phones, "\\b[-0-9]+\\b") %>%
    str_remove_all("-")
# Can also specify that you need at least 5 numbers/hyphens 
# in a row to match
numbers2 = str_extract(phones, "\\b[-0-9]{5,}\\b") %>%
    str_remove_all("-")
```

That way, you're not locked into a fixed format for the number of hyphens that appear in the number (my suggested regex allows for any number).

Comment: Yeah this works perfectly, I'll use your regex pattern in this case for being more reusable!

Answer (score 0):

If you (like me) prefer to use base-R  and want to keep the regex as simple as possible you could do something like this:

```
phone_split <- lapply(
  strsplit(phones, " "), 
  function(x) {
    name_part <- grepl("[^-0-9]", x)
    c(
      name = paste(x[name_part], collapse = " "),
      phone = x[!name_part]
    )
  }
)
phone_split
[[1]]
        name        phone 
       "Ann" "077-789663" 

[[2]]
       name       phone 
"Johnathan"  "99656565" 

[[3]]
           name           phone 
"Maria2 office"   "099-65-6569" 

do.call(rbind, phone_split)

     name            phone        
[1,] "Ann"           "077-789663" 
[2,] "Johnathan"     "99656565"   
[3,] "Maria2 office" "099-65-6569"
```